# Does the Frontier Justice get revenge crits when Combat Sentries are destroyed?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-engineer

I tried a Gunslinger engineer build and was using Frontier Justice.  I would drop my combat sentries in locations where they seemed really likely to destroyed thinking I would get bonus crits.

However, I was having a bad night (or perhaps all my opponents were having really excellent night) and I was dying too frequently to see if I was even getting the bonus crits.  Does anyone know if this works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It most definitely works. This is my new preferred way to play my engineer. You can keep track of the # of revenge crits you have racked up in the bottom right corner of the default interface above the ammo counter. One of the nice advantages of using the mini-sentries with the Frontier Justice is the ability to blow up your sentry intentionally to get the crits, since rebuilding mini-sentries is quick and cheap. It's an effective way to provide your team with additional offensive prowess: critical shotgun shots do a significant amount of damage.

Keep in mind that you get 2 per kill, 1 per assist, and your mini sentry is much more likely to get an assist than a kill due to it's lower damage output.

Answer (score 3):

The frontier justice does not care what kind of sentry you have, though it might be harder for your mini-sentry to get kills in the first place.